# How to "promise" that a value will be a certain type

Tags: racket, typed-racket

If I have this function in typed/racket:

```
(: random-if-empty (-> (U Image-Color "empty") Image-Color))
(define (random-if-empty s)
  (cond
    [(equal? s "empty") (random-color)]
    [else s]))
```

Which returns a random color if it's input is `"empty"`, otherwise it returns it's input, how do I stop the Type Checker from saying that `s` (in `[else s]`) can be an `Image-Color` **or** `"empty"` instead of the expected `Image-Color`?  Or is there a better way overall to do this?  I am using the `typed/2htdp/image` library, which is where `Image-Color` comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `equal?` predicate can inform the type system that a variable is or is not a certain value, however, this only works for certain values of certain types. It works for some simple types (booleans, symbols, empty lists, void, and `0` and `1`), but it doesn't work for most other data types, including strings.

(This might have something to do with strings being mutable, I'm not sure.)

The way to solve this is to make your own predicate for the `"empty"` string a different way. Typed racket provides the form [`make-predicate`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html#%28part._.Generating_.Predicates_.Automatically%29) which can turn some simple "flat" types into predicates. You can use it like this:

```
(define my-empty-pred? (make-predicate "empty"))
```

This new predicate will be able to use [occurrence typing](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/occurrence-typing.html) more directly to tell the type system that if `(my-empty-pred? x)` returns true, then `x` has the type `"empty"`, and if it returns false then `x`'s type should not contain `"empty"`. So you can use it in your example like:

```
(: random-if-empty (-> (U Image-Color "empty") Image-Color))
(define (random-if-empty s)
  (cond
    [(my-empty-pred? s) (random-color)]
    [else s]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of [occurrence typing](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/occurrence-typing.html) to tell the type checker that your `s` in the second case cannot be a string.

```
#lang typed/racket

(require typed/2htdp/image)

(define (random-color) : Image-Color
  (color 0 0 0)) ;; dummy

(: random-if-empty (-> (U Image-Color "empty") Image-Color))
(define (random-if-empty s)
  (cond
    [(string? s) (random-color)]
    [else s]))
```

Why does `string?` work and not `(equal? s "empty)"`? I don't know, but I guess Typed Racket isn't that smart.

You can also use [assertions](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/Utilities.html?q=assert#%28def._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fextra-procs..rkt%29._assert%29%29)

```
(: random-if-empty (-> (U Image-Color "empty") Image-Color))
(define (random-if-empty s)
  (cond
    [(equal? s "empty") (random-color)]
    [else (assert s string?)]))
```

If your types are really complicated you might have to resort to [casting](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html?q=assert#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fprims..rkt%29._cast%29%29), which are written just like asserts. But I've given these solutions in order of preference. Casting should be a last resort.

Comment: I guess it doesn't work for equal? because it isn't a predicate.

Comment: Changing it to `string?` changes the behavior of the program if an `Image-Color` can be a string. Since in `typed/2htdp/image` it can, Gibstick's first solution is wrong.